# rails 4 using cdn but css asset_path not using prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Environment: heroku (cedar)

Rails: 4.0

Ruby: 2.0

In my production.rb I have

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

And for image_tag helpers etc in my main layout, everything is pointing to the correct asset location (using as3).

The issue is that my css file: scroll-up-down.css.erb doesn't appear to use the correct asset path.

```
.nav_up{
    background: #fff url(<%= asset_path 'scroller-arrow_up.png' %>) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    left:30px;
    }
```

which is resolving as

> '/assets/scroller-arrow_up.png'

in the compiled css file?

Any ideas? Everything else works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaned assets and pushed again after another precompile. It seems to work now.